# HD paths on MyEthereumWallet

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet, private-key, hd-wallets, backup

I hae some coins on MyEthereumWallet, that I can see in block explorer, but can not access it. I think that the mnemoic and password is correct. My assumption is that I messed up something with the HD path. I'm only storing Ether on this wallet. What are the possible HD pathes that I should try?

I think I created the wallet some 1.5 - 2 years ago. MEW also changed during that time. Maybe the default HD path changed, or there was a possibility to switch to other option that is not there anymore, i dont know.

If you have any idea, please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Here is link with derivation paths that were common a few years ago https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/84#issuecomment-292324521.

Answer (score 1):

There's a chance that when you initally created your account, you didn't use a password. Try accessing your mnemonic phrase and see if your account shows up, for example using [MyCrypto Desktop](https://download.mycrypto.com/) or [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/).

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help

Answer (score 1):

The following is the bip32 derivation path of the ETH coin

m/44'/60'/0'/0

But as said by @Morten , you can access your accounts just by the mnemonic phase if it is correct

Hope this helps

Comment: This never changed?

Does the MEW care about typos in mnemoic?

Comment: NO, as described here (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki#path-levels), they are specified for every type of coins. And yes, if you add a mnemonic that is invalid, MEW won't let you proceed

Comment: so password is not even necessary for restoring it?

Comment: Does the password mean wallet password? AFAIK, mneonics are enough to generate the addresses and the private keys associated with them and so if youhave your mnemonic, you should be able to access them but just not inside MEW as your 'MEW account' is password protected. You can download the offline tool of this [link](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english) and paste your mnemonic and you must see the addresses and their PKs

Comment: I tried changing some words in the mnemoic, and I got mnemoic checksum error.
Is there a mechanism that protects from misspelling the words in the mnemoic?
If I don't have checksum error, does that mean that the mnemoic is correct?

Comment: You can check it using this [link](https://iancoleman.io/bip39/#english). Yes, correct, you can only use words defined [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt). You can learn more about the checksum and algorithm over [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/mnemonic-generation-bip39-simply-explained-e9ac18db9477). No error does mean that you have correct mnemonic